# printf prints twice for some reason, cout seems okay though

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I've written a library and I'm trying to statically link it to my main program. My main program is written in C++, but the library is in C. I noticed some of the debugging printf statements in my library running twice where they shouldn't for some reason, so I started commenting out code. I'm now left with this (comments excluded):

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
    include "audio.h"
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    audio_test();
    std::cout << "World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The function audio test is not interesting at all. This is from a C file that I'm trying to use in my C++ project.

```
void audio_test()
{
    printf("TEST\n");
}
```

The output from my program is this:

```
Hello
TEST

TEST
World
```

I have no idea at this point why this is happening.

Comment: Missing "<<" after "Hello" and before std::endl.

Comment: @Alex: Just to be clear, you're saying that the two snippets are showing your code in its entirety?

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable example.  Then compile it and make sure that it does in fact do what you say it does.

Comment: Sorry about the missing <<, I'm editing the code over ssh and it's hard to copy/paste. However, I've noticed that there was another file included in audio.c, and when commented out the bug goes away. Somehow that file is causing the problem.

Comment: The above is not a cut and paste (as it does not compile). Please cut and paste all code that we need to build (including header files).

Comment: maybe you have a macro named printf

Comment: Not only does it seem to print TEST twice, it also inserts another newline between the calls, if the output provided by @Alex is correct.

Comment: Since this question no longer accurately reflects the real problem I'm seeing, I'm just going to close it and talk to the person who wrote the other file I'm using.

Comment: @Alex: You got 666 rep. /offtopic

Answer (score 2):

Call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true)` and it will probably work better.

Comment: I thought the standard required them to always be in sync..?